# Надо,чтобы код выводил текущею репутацию юзера

Tags: php, sql

```
<?php

session_start();

?>

 <html>
 <head>
<title>Мой профиль</title>
</head>
<body>
<p> Ваша репутация: <?php 

include 'bd.php';

$reputations = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT reputation FROM users WHERE login = '$login'");

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($reputations); 

echo $row['reputation'];

?> 
 </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Ошибки нет, но не выводит 0

Comment: добавьте в код под строкой запроса к бд эти строки `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($reputations);

echo $row['reputation'];`

Comment: Та же ошибка возникает

Comment: А если урать echo $reputations; , то ничего не выводит

Comment: добавьте ваш код в пост с вопросом, что бы можно было видеть, как и куда вы его прописали.

Comment: О каком коде вы говорите?

Comment: о том коде, который у вас есть на текущий момент. То есть, в свой код вы внесли изменения _(добавили две строки)_ Теперь отредактируйте первый ваш пост, чтобы можно было видеть, что и куда вы прописали.

Comment: Изменил код,,,,

Comment: И да, другая ошибка, я не знаю почему в предыдущий раз не изменилась, видимо я забыл сохранить

Comment: в строку запроса подставлена переменная $login - посмотрите что в ней хранится?

Comment: текст ошибки напишите в ваш первый пост.

Comment: тут нет начала переменной (знака доллара) `row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($reputations);`

Comment: 1) В переменной логин хранится логин, который пользователь ввел при авторизации.

Comment: сейчас перепишу

Comment: если вы уверены в том, что переменная $login действительно хранит верное значение, то исправьте синтаксическую ошибку _(добавьте доллар перед row)_ и код выполнится.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, сейчас пересмотрю значение $login и исправлю.

Comment: что бы удобнее было проверять параметры запроса, строку запроса надо сохранять  в переменную, и выводить её в браузер. Т.е, так: `echo $sql = "SELECT reputation FROM users WHERE login = '$login'";

$reputations = mysqli_query($db, $sql);`

Comment: Эдуард, спасибо за помощь, я просто убрал "WHERE login = '$login'". Я так понимаю потому, что сессия была открыта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Рекомендую добавить этот код перед `session_start();` чтобы увидеть ошибки. И добавить "кавычки"

```
SELECT `reputation` FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '$login'
```

Немного переделаный код, чтобы увидеть что на самом деле происходит.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

session_start();

?>

 <html>
 <head>
<title>Мой профиль</title>
</head>
<body>
<p> Ваша репутация: <?php 

include 'bd.php';

$reputations = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT `reputation` FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '$login'");

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($reputations); 

echo '<pre>';
print_r($row);
echo '</pre>';

?> 
 </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Этот код отобразит `$row` как массив. Если он все же будет пуст, то нужно искать ошибку в синтаксисе или в файле `'bd.php';`.

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($row);
echo '</pre>';
```

**Вобщем все же я рекомендую переделать под `PDO`.**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DBNAME;charset=utf8", 'root', 'PASSWORD');

$pr = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `reputation` FROM `users` WHERE `login` = :login");
$pr->execute(array(
    'login' => $login
));
$data = $pr->fetchAll();

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Я просто убрал "WHERE login = '$login'" и все заработало. Я так понимаю потому, что сессия была открыта, но спасибо за помощь